# Not finding other files in the same workspace folder in Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

This is probably a very simple question. But it's driving me nuts and I can't find the solution. I setup Eclipse and PyDev in my Windows box and I've written a class to do something. Then I created another .py file to run a program that users that class, but the program cannot find the class.

It works well if I put all code in the same file, which is umanagable, but not in separate 
files.

Also, I looked at my PYTHONPATH variable in Eclipse and it has the path of the folder i have my code in.

Any ideas why it doesn't recognize all the files in the same folder?

Comment: Please add more info... a screenshot of your pydev package explorer of the project and of the error you're having would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to import the other class from the other file into your original file to be able to use the class.

For example, `from otherfile import OtherClass`

Otherwise, please add more info.